# SQL Transactions with Commit and Rollback

Tags: sql, transactions, commit

Can someone tell me if I am correct in understanding the use of `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

If I want to update a table but want the ability to UNDO my update in case of an error would this code be the proper way to go about it?

```
START TRANSACTION;  

update ar 
set doc_no = gltrans.reference  
from plxx.dbo.ar 
inner join plxx.dbo.gltrans on gltrans.LNKUNIQUE = ar.UNIQUE_CD
where gltrans.LNKUNIQUE = ar.UNIQUE_CD 
  and ar.DOC_NO <> gltrans.REFERENCE

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pattern that I use for rolling back a transaction on error in a sql statement:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150034/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041906-1.shtml

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION    -- Start the transaction

update ar 
set doc_no = gltrans.reference  
from plxx.dbo.ar 
inner join plxx.dbo.gltrans on gltrans.LNKUNIQUE = ar.UNIQUE_CD
where gltrans.LNKUNIQUE = ar.UNIQUE_CD 
and ar.DOC_NO <> gltrans.REFERENCE

 -- If we reach here, success!
COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
-- Whoops, there was an error
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
 ROLLBACK

-- Raise an error with the details of the exception
DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
      @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have an error occur after starting a transaction & before the commit statement anything within that statement will be rolled back. You can also include Try/Catch statements if you want some additional functionality around error management, for example logging of the failure.

Comment: I have just made one to many mistakes where you update and forget to include the proper WHERE clause so you end up updating the entire table/column, i was told there is a way to rollback if you use a start/commit so was looking for the proper code

Comment: Okay, when you forget the where statement it doesn't invoke an 'error' that will automatically be caught by using transactions. Depending on your DBMS though, you can roll back your database to a point in time using the transaction log. This will depend on your DBMS and certain configuration options such as the engine the table uses.

Comment: If you're concerned about updating all of the rows, you could compare the @@ROWCOUNT value after update to the count of the table rows in conjunction with try/catch to rollback in the event that they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` instead of using `START TRANSACTION`. after executing the `UPDATE` command, you can roll it back by using `ROLLBACK` then to confirm the transaction use `COMMIT`.